# Can different yarn versions cause yarn install to modify the content of yarn.lock files?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

My question is: when I run `yarn install` locally, it modifies the `yarn.lock` file I pulled from a Github source. There is nothing changed in package.json file.
My best guess is that I am using `yarn 1.22.18` locally, but the latest commit of `yarn.lock` on Github (which I just pulled) uses 1.22.19 to generate.
**Could different yarn versions cause this issue?**

ps: previously, `yarn.lock` file on Github source was generated by `yarn 1.22.17`, even though I am using `yarn 1.22.18`. when I do `yarn install`, there is nothing changed in my local `yarn.lock` file.

I did some research on my issue, but cannot find any good articles about this problem ([Why is my yarn.lock file changing when running yarn install after incrementing version in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296221/why-is-my-yarn-lock-file-changing-when-running-yarn-install-after-incrementing-v)). If someone thinks this issue is a duplicate, please kindly provide a link and I will close this issue.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: what output did you get if you use `--frozen-lockfile`?