# yarn.lock file gets modified unintentionally

Tags: git, github, dependencies

[Image of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6eo0.png)

Why does this `yarn.lock` file get modified after I run: `npm i`? Shouldn't the status read: `Already up to date`?

I tried to delete the repo and clone a new one but I am still seeing this happen unintentionally.

Comment: Personally I dislike the concept of checking `yarn.lock` in.  If I build on Linux, MacOS, and Windows the file is changed even though they claim it won't be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my yarn.lock file changing when running yarn install after incrementing version in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296221/why-is-my-yarn-lock-file-changing-when-running-yarn-install-after-incrementing-v)